# Define Projections for layers with multiple locations in MXD's

Tags: arcgis-10.2, coordinate-system, arcpy

```
    # Script to use Layers in MXD source file paths to locate and redefine projections

import arcpy, glob, os, sys, arcgisscripting

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("N:\MXDs\_ThomaKL\MXD GPS Valves\GPS_Shapefile_Paths.mxd")

for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    if lyr.supports("DATASOURCE"):
        print lyr.dataSource

from arcpy import env, mapping
path = lyr.dataSource
env.workspace = path
env.overwriteOutput = True

print 'Reading files from ' + path

sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(103133)

x=0
z=x+1
NoProjCount=0
FileList= arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(lyr)
for lyr in FileList:
    desc = arcpy.Describe(lyr)
    SR = desc.spatialReference
    if SR.name == "Unknown":
        print "Projection of " + str(lyr) + " is " + SR.name + " so defining projection."
        f = open('NoProjection.txt', 'a')
        f.write(str(lyr)+"\n")
        f.close()
        arcpy.DefineProjection_management(lyr, sr) 
        NoProjCount=NoProjCount+1
    else:    
        print lyr + " is projected " + str(SR.name)
```

so I have a script that works, but it only defines the projection for the very last Layer in the MXD and not the entire list of layers (there are around 50). I can tell I am missing something but I am not sure what. below is what the NoProjection.txt file has stored in it.

> Valves.shp GPS Points\DataCollectedLater-Valves\Valve_GPS Points GPS
>   Points\DataCollectedLater-Valves\Valve_GPS Points GPS
>   Points\DataCollectedLater-Valves\Valve_GPS Points GPS
>   Points\DataCollectedLater-Valves\Valve_GPS Points GPS
>   Points\DataCollectedLater-Valves\Valve_GPS Points GPS
>   Points\DataCollectedLater-Valves\Valve_GPS Points GPS
>   Points\DataCollectedLater-Valves\Valve_GPS Points GPS
>   Points\DataCollectedLater-Valves\Valve_GPS Points

Comment: What is being written in your NoProjection.txt file? Do you see all of the layers or just the last one?

Comment: @MaryBeth the projection file only has the information for the layer that was defined, basically it had the name of the layer and if it was located in a grouplayer.

Comment: I understand what it's supposed to store--I'm curious if it has all 50 layer names in it or if it just contains the name of the one layer that was actually reprojected. It helps us debug your code to know where the problem may be--is the script iterating through the block where SR.name == "unknown" or is it only considering it a true statement on the last line of code.

Comment: This is unrelated to where you are stuck but to present a cleaner code snippet there are four libraries that you are importing and not using here. As much as you can try to show us the *minimum* code in order to illustrate where you are stuck.

Comment: @MaryBeth Okay so I will say again, the .txt file has only the last layer in the MXD and not the entire list. SR.name == "unknown" appears to be seeing the one file and defining it but I am not sure why?  do you want me to post the .txt file?

Comment: Have you tried to check within the mxd to see if other layers have updated? No guarantees, but I wonder if there is the possibility of the .txt being locked as the iteration is happening.  I'd be curious to see what happens if you move the open(...) before the for statement and not close until the whole iteration is complete.

Comment: the .txt file does for some reason have the group layer information in it 8 times.

Comment: If it's the last one repeated all the time, it's because the layer isn't created new every time it's run--it's just appending.

Comment: You have quite a few print statements in there. Are those printing as expected? I would start my debugging efforts there.

Comment: @MaryBeth yes I have checked them but I also have a message when the script ends to tell me what files were defined.  I will try your suggestion and see if it will run the rest of the layers in the MXD.  thanks

Comment: @Mintx  I want the Print statements in there so that I can tell that it is working, I am visual and as the do not affect the programs overall working I want to leave them there.  I will not be the only person using this and I think it will help those that do not understand Python.

Comment: @popboarder Understood; I meant that if you have 50 layers, I would expect at least 50 print statements from your `for lyr in FileList` loop. If you only get 10 or 1 print statement, that would indicate a problem.

Comment: @Mintx Oh okay well all the layers do show up with the first print statement when it ask to list it out.

Comment: @MaryBeth  when I moved the open(...) part to before the for statement but as I thought it is opening before it actually reads the Filelist and just creates a blanket .txt file.  in theory the way it reads now i wanted it to grab the location each shapefile using the layer location and define its projection. to do that it needs to read the list that is printed in the beginning of the scripted.

Answer (score 1):

There's a slight typo here:

> FileList = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(lyr)

This should be:

> FileList = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(**mxd**)

-- **edit** --

It looks like some things are out of order, try this instead.

```
    # Script to use Layers in MXD source file paths to locate and redefine projections

import arcpy, glob, os, sys, arcgisscripting 
from arcpy import env, mapping

x=0 
z=x+1 
NoProjCount=0 
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(103133) 
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("N:\MXDs\_ThomaKL\MXD GPS Valves\GPS_Shapefile_Paths.mxd")

for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    if lyr.supports("DATASOURCE"):
        print lyr.dataSource
        path = lyr.dataSource
        print 'Reading files from ' + path
        env.workspace = path
        env.overwriteOutput = True

        desc = arcpy.Describe(lyr)
        SR = desc.spatialReference
        if SR.name == "Unknown":
            print "Projection of " + str(lyr) + " is " + SR.name + " so defining projection."
            f = open('NoProjection.txt', 'a')
            f.write(str(lyr)+"\n")
            f.close()
            arcpy.DefineProjection_management(lyr, sr) 
            NoProjCount=NoProjCount+1
        else:    
            print lyr + " is projected " + str(SR.name)
```

Comment: should the other references to lyr be changed to mxd as well?  below the FileList= arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)

Comment: No, those should be fine.

Comment: I made the change to the FileList = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd), but i got a Traceback error for Line 25,  I will post below

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "N:\MXDs\_ThomaKL\MXD GPS Valves\DefineProjWDTest", line 25, in <module>
    desc = arcpy.Describe(lyr)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 1234, in Describe
    return gp.describe(value)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 374, in describe
    self._gp.Describe(*gp_fixargs(args, True)))
IOError: "GPS Points" does not exist

Comment: It looks like that error is saying `GPS Points` can't be described because it doesn't exist?

Comment: i think it is because that is a group layer and it is not able to read past that.  I'll ungroup the layer and see if that works.

Comment: Oh, I see now. I've edited my answer.

Comment: hey that worked my other one worked to after I took out the extra group layer and the already projected layers.  Thanks for the help you are the best.